# vscode Generate Type Members equivalent

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, intellij-idea

I've been using a lot of Generate Type Members hotkey `Alt + Ins` in IntelliJ and Android Studio.

Is there any alternative in VS Code?